# ADO.NET DAO Layer Design With Base DAO

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a database with a number of stored procedures. These stored procedures provide the basic CRUD operations against the data. I'm trying to create a DAO layer with separate DAOs for each domain class (Album, Artist, Genre, Review, etc) which uses a common Base DAO.

Using the Album DAO as an example, this is what I have so far:

```
 public class AlbumDao
{

    //Members
    BaseDao baseDao = new BaseDao();

    //Public Methods

    public Album GetAlbumById(int id)
    {
        Album album;

        //Get Album
        List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, id));

        DataTable dataTable = baseDao.ExecuteQuery("GetAlbumById", parameters);
        album = AlbumMapper(dataTable.Rows[0]);

        //Return
        return album;

    }

    public List<Album> GetAllAlbums()
    {
        return GetAlbumList("GetAlbums");
    }

    public List<Album> GetAllFiveStarAlbums()
    {
        List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int, 5));

        return GetAlbumList("GetAlbumsByRating", parameters);
    }

    public void InsertAlbum(Album newAlbum)
    {
        List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, newAlbum.Title));
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Composer", SqlDbType.VarChar, newAlbum.Composer));
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@ReleaseYear", SqlDbType.Int, newAlbum.ReleaseYear));
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int, newAlbum.Rating));
        parameters.Add(new Parameter("@IsFranchise", SqlDbType.Bit, newAlbum.IsFranchise));

        baseDao.ExecuteNonQuery("AddAlbum", parameters);
    }


    //List Method
    private List<Album> GetAlbumList(string procedureName, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
    {

        List<Album> albumList = new List<Album>();            

        try
        {                
            DataTable dataTable = baseDao.ExecuteQuery(procedureName, parameters);

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                albumList.Add(AlbumMapper(row));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return albumList;

    }



    //Mappers
    private Album AlbumMapper(DataRow dr)
    {
        Album album = new Album();

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("AlbumId"))
        {
            album.Id = Int32.Parse(dr["AlbumId"].ToString());
        }

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Title"))
        {
            album.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
        }

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Composer"))
        {
            album.Composer = dr["Composer"].ToString();
        }

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("ReleaseYear"))
        {
            album.ReleaseYear = Int32.Parse(dr["ReleaseYear"].ToString());
        }

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Rating"))
        {
            album.Rating = Int32.Parse(dr["Rating"].ToString());
        }

        if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("isFranchase"))
        {
            album.IsFranchise = Boolean.Parse(dr["isFranchase"].ToString());
        }


        return album;
    }

}
```

And this is the base DAO:

```
public class BaseDao
{
    string connectionString = "xxx";
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string procedureName, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
    {

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            //Create Command
            command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Add Parameters If Exist
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (Parameter parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter.Name, parameter.Type).Value = parameter.Value;
                }
            }                    

            //Populate DataTable With Stored Procedure Results
            try
            {
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);                    
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);                                       
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }

        //Return 
        return dataTable;

    }

    public void ExecuteNonQuery(string procedureName, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
    {


        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            //Create Command
            command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Add Parameters If Exist
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (Parameter parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter.Name, parameter.Type).Value = parameter.Value;
                }
            }

            //Execute
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Here is the Album class (just a simple class with constructors and properties):

```
    public class Album
{

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Album() { }

    public Album(int id, string title, string composer, int releaseYear, int rating, bool isFranchise)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Composer = composer;
        this.ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.Rating = rating;
        this.IsFranchise = isFranchise;

    }

    public Album(string title, string composer, int releaseYear, int rating, bool isFranchise)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Composer = composer;
        this.ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.Rating = rating;
        this.IsFranchise = isFranchise;

    }

    //PROPERTIES
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Composer { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public bool IsFranchise { get; set; }

}
```

So for methods that return a single Album object such as `GetAlbumById`, I execute the query by passing in the SP name and its parameters to the base DAO, and then take the data from row 0.

For methods that return a list of Album objects such as `GetAllFiveStarAlbums`, I also call `ExecuteQuery` but from the `GetAlbumList` method that iterates through the DataTable and builds a list of Album objects.

In all cases, I use a mapper method to convert the DataTable row to an Album object.

You can imagine the DAOs for Artist, Review etc structured the same way.

I'm unsure if this is good design so I'd appreciate some feedback and advice?

Another thought that occurred to me is that the Album DAO could just have a single List method which takes the name of the stored procedure and SP parameters as parameters, but that would require passing that information from the BLL and I don't think the BLL should know about the names of database stored procedures.

Comment: Please post the code for Album.

Comment: @paparazzo I've posted the Album class now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DataTable has a lot of overhead.

In the code you have a lot of overhead.  Album AlbumMapper is called for every row and you parse for every column name.

I think it would be a lot clean if you based is on Album and return List

```
public List<Album> ExecuteQuery(string procedureName, List<Parameter> parameters = null)
{
```

Use `Album` also for the query.  Have nullable Properties and null means don't search on that.

```
public List<Album> SearchAlbum(Album album)
{
    List<Album> searchAlbum = new List<Album>();
    List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    string spName = "GetAlbums";

    if (album.Rating != null)
    {
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int, 5));
         spName = "GetAlbumsByRating";
    else if (album.Rating != null) 
    {
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, id));
         spName = "GetAlbumsByRating";
    }
    else if (album.Tile != null) 
    {
         parameters.Clear();
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, newAlbum.Title));
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Composer", SqlDbType.VarChar, newAlbum.Composer));
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@ReleaseYear", SqlDbType.Int, newAlbum.ReleaseYear));
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@Rating", SqlDbType.Int, newAlbum.Rating));
         parameters.Add(new Parameter("@IsFranchise", SqlDbType.Bit, newAlbum.IsFranchise));
         spName = "AddAlbum";
    }

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        //Create Command
        command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (Parameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter.Name, parameter.Type).Value = parameter.Value;
            } 
        }

        //here would need another branch for an insert

        using(SqlDataReader rdr = command.Execute())
        {
             while(rdr.Read())
             { 
                 Album album = new Album();
                 album.ID = rdr.GetInt(0);
                 album.Title = rdr.GetString(1);
                 ...
                 searchAlbum.Add(album);
             }
        }
  }
  return searchAlbum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not save yourself all those ADO.NET and Datatable to custom class headaches and use an ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)? And then you simply have a bunch of Services, e.g. an `AlbumService` which has a `Get(int id)` method, etc. And you can then have an `IAlbumService` so you can do IoC/DI etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but let's assume I'm constrained to using vanilla ADO.NET for the moment. I wish to know the best way to structure the DAO layer.